# arrow function filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, arrow-functions

I wonder why is this udefinded:

```
const numbers2 = [45, 5, 9, 16, 25];

const myFunction1 = (numbers2) =>{numbers2.filter(number=>{return number>6})}; 

console.log("Soy filter con arrowFunction: " + myFunction1(numbers2)); // Soy filter con arrowFunction: undefined
```

Comment: with curly brackets, you need a `return` statement. or use without curlies.

Comment: You are not returning anything from `myFunction1`.

Comment: remove braces `{}`; change to `myFunction1 = numbers2 => numbers2.filter(...)`; or better `const greaterThan6 = nums => nums.filter(n => n > 6)`

Answer (score 1):

You having a missing return. See below in the code it is added.

```
const numbers2 = [45, 5, 9, 16, 25];

const myFunction1 = (numbers2) =>{
  return numbers2.filter(number=>{   // <===== missing return was here
    return number>6
  }
  )
};

console.log("Soy filter con arrowFunction: " + myFunction1(numbers2));
```

Comment: Nina Scholzt is right. Brackets were the issue. Delete them and will run perfectly.   const numbers2 = [45, 5, 9, 16, 25];

const myFunction1 = (numbers2) => numbers2.filter(number=>{return number>6});

console.log("Soy filter con arrowFunction: " + myFunction1(numbers2));